# Sharing a GIF on Giphy after GIF and Facebook post has been deleted

Tags: facebook

A GIF uploaded via giphy.com has been shared via Facebook. Afterwards both the Facebook post and the GIF on Giphy has been deleted. Other people can still share and see the GIF.

Do you know why? What can be done to avoid this?
It seems that GIFs on Giphy can be edited, but I guess not after deleting them, right?

**Update:** it seems that the GIF is cached by Facebook on *.fbcdn.net/v/* - this cache can be manually cleared via https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/ but in this case the GIF has already been deleted on Giphy and returns only a 404 error. Facebook seems to ignore the 404 error and lets people continue share this link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems as if Facebook clears its cache after getting a 404 error for longer time. Now after a couple of days, Facebook displays "This content is not available".